# How to setup timeout callback event using angular rest service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I save my data using angular service factory, how do I handle the timeout event, lets say if the internet connection is unstable, now I end up with a loading screen infinitely, so I want to set timeout after few seconds if the response is not received, my rest service looks like this:

```
.factory('Deal', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/deals/:id/:action.json", {
        id : "@id",
        action : "@action"
    }, {
        query : {
            method : "GET",
            isArray : false
        },
        update : {
            method : "POST",
            params : {
                    action : 'update'
            }
        }
    });
} ])
```

And this is how I call the save method:

```
  Deal
    .save(
        $scope.deal,
        function(data) {
        },
        function(err) {
        });
```

Comment: See the following and look for the timeout property ... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration option has a `timeout` property that may help you

```
query : {
        method : "GET",
        isArray : false,
        timeout:5000, //In millisecond
    },
```

You can use the `$http.defaults` configuration to override this at global level.
See documentation on `$http` or `$resource` https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.3/docs/api/ng/service/$http

When the timeout lapses the underlying resource promise will be rejected and you willland on error callback